# How do you use scanf in a for loop so it does not stop looping on the first try?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

```
for(int i=0;i<num; i++)
{
    char word[32];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",word);
    makeDictionary(word, readDictionary);
}
```

I have a program where I want to ask user for certain strings n times (with spacing allowed). However, when they input for example n = 2, it only loops once and exists. I know there is something wrong with my scanf.

I do Java and I'm a beginner at C. The way strings are done is very different.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: In C it's very important to check the return values of functions you call and react according to what that means.

Comment: How many times it will loop depends on `num`, unfortunately we can't know what `num` is because the image you posted shows too little. Also rather use text than image if you can, images are very annoying.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Thanks for the effort you put into transcribing the picture. But it just demonstrates why pictures of text are not appreciated on StackOverflow, because the code you typed is not exactly the code in the picture. And the difference in the format specifier string might even be relevant. The author of a question has the option to copy-paste the text, nobody else. So the author should replace picture with text.

Comment: Hidaisyen, please provide a [mre], as text, directly here. Because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 (@Bonny you commented to the same effect, please try typing `[mre]` into an approriate comment like yours.)

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 int N;
 do
 {
      printf("Give me number of words :");
      scanf("%d",&N);
 }while(N<1);


 for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
 {char str[20];
      printf("\nGive me the %d word :",i+1);
      scanf("%s[^\n]",str);
      printf("%s",str);
 }

}
```